# How to Centre Grid of Divs

Tags: html, css, grid

I have set up a grid layout that is responsive and stacks as you decrease the page size.

However, how can I center the three divs? You will notice that at full expansion they are slightly off center.

http://www.naturettl.com/shop/

Thanks.

Comment: What browser are you using? I cannot see the difference in sides...

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with many methods, one of these methods is `display:inline`:

```
div.Box {
    width: 20%;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
}

#Container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ukutgfos/)** *(this with `percent` width)*

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ukutgfos/1/)** *(this with `px` width)*

```
div.Box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

another method is make div.Box `float: left;` then give a fixed `width` to parent then add `margin: auto` for make it center.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ukutgfos/2/)**

```
div.Box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
```

but if you want to make it responsive you should write some `media` query for other resolution.